# find for which $\alpha, \beta$ does $\int\limits_{100}^{\infty}\frac{1}{xln(x)^{\alpha}ln(ln(x))^{\beta}}dx$ converge

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

> find for which $\alpha, \beta$ the following integral converges:
>
> $\int\limits_{100}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x\ln(x)^{\alpha}\ln(\ln(x))^{\beta}}\,dx$

I thought about trying substitution and got to $\int\limits_{\ln(100)}^{\infty}\frac{1}{u^{\alpha}\ln(u)^{\beta}}\,du$

and I thought about separating to different cases here but it seemed too complicated.

also thought about another substitution which gets $\int\limits_{\ln(\ln(100))}^{\infty}\frac{1}{e^{v\alpha -v}v^{\beta}}\,dv$

but this seems even more confusing.

So I want to ask:

1. are my substitutions not correct by any chance?
2. tips on how to approach this question?

Comment: By $\ln(\ln x)^\beta$, do you mean $\ln[(\ln x)^\beta]=\beta\ln\ln x$ or $[\ln\ln x]^\beta$, which is often denoted $\ln^\beta\ln x$?

Answer (score 1):

You were right by trying to start with a substitution. After you get

$$\int^{\infty}_{\ln(100)} \frac{1}{u^\alpha\ln(u)^\beta}$$
From this, we can do a p-test and find that the integral will converge for all $$\alpha \in (1, \infty)$$
or
$$\alpha = 1 \text{ and } \beta \in (1, \infty)$$

Comment: How do you show it converges if $\alpha > 1$?

Comment: We know it converges for $\alpha > 1$ because our p-test would give $$\int^{\infty}_{\ln(100)} \frac{1}{u^\alpha \ln(u)^beta}$$
is less than
$$\int^{\infty}_{\ln(100)} \frac{1}{u^\alpha}$$ which will converge for all $\alpha > 1$

Comment: isn't this true only for $\beta \geq 0$?

Comment: Yes it is, otherwise the integral would diverge

Comment: so you agree your answer is incorrect...
i'm not sure it would diverge but we can't simply say it converges.
this is why trying to solve this way seemed too complicated to me

Comment: My answer is not incorrect, I don't understand what you're saying

Answer (score 0):

Hint : Since find the values of $\alpha,\beta$ necessary to apply the [Integral test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence) and use [Cauchy's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) to determine convergence of the series.